# Mostrar notificación cuando el navegador está minimizado o el usuario no está navegando en la pestaña

Tags: html5, signalr, notificaciones

Estoy trabajando en una app donde utilizo SignalR y las notificaciones de HTML5. Lo que necesito es mandar una notificación cuando el usuario no se encuentre activo en ese momento o tenga el navegador minimizado, algo similar a lo que hace Facebook, de aquí mi pregunta. de qué forma puedo saber cuando mi navegador esta minimizado o el usuario no se encuentra actualmente en dicha pestaña?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de unas horas de búsqueda, logré darle solución a mi problema utilizando [ifvisible.js](https://github.com/serkanyersen/ifvisible.js/) es muy sencillo de utilizar y tiene varios métodos que son muy útiles para determinados casos. tales como: cuando el navegador esta minimizado o el usuario no esta trabajando en esa pestaña. Espero le sea de ayuda a alguien más